# Best Practices - How can I register users to my database using chrome extension login?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth

Im looking for the safe way to authenticate with Oauth2 and send the credentials(email and token) to my server. I want to achieve this by using a Google Chrome extension, and must be in Javascript language. I need to synchronize a Google Chrome extension login with my server database and then with an android app.

I've found this tutorial provided by Google:
developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth

The tutorial shows how to implement an authentication but I'm not sure if this is safe for what i want to achieve.

The image below shows an schema of what I think Google proposes:
[Google Oauth Schema](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/571x331q90/540/a1EZPn.png)

If someone send to my server a custom token I have no way to validate if the token belongs to a Google session. What i want to:[Custom authentication](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/737x252q90/911/ZWxVSR.png)

**My questions:** Is there any safe way to send credentials(email and token) to my server database? What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use SSL it should be safe enough. The credentials are already accessible client side so at this point you just have to worry about protecting the credentials in transit and on your server.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as I know isn't enough if I want to login/autoregister to my server and use the same session on that Javascript client-side and other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Think this solves what I was asking:

[Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow?hl=en#using_one-time-code_flow)

As its explained I can send the **one-time authorization code** to my server and validate the session there. I can get the token on my own server and return it to the Javascript client.

Hope this help to someone! :D